# Idiom meaning diverting somebody's attention from a topic which you don't want to talk on

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Is there an idiom or expression which means diverting somebody's attention  with profuse talk about irrelevant things and trying to change a topic which is unpleasant to you or which you just don't want to discuss? Like this:

> “Why did you lie?”
>
> ”Uh, such nice weather, isn't it? You  know, last weekend when we were on vacation on the lake....”

I have heard of *to talk one's head off*, but as far as I understand it means just talking a lot and being boring, doesn't it?

Comment: Your example is hardly "diverting attention". It's outright refusing to answer the question or acknowledge that you're not answering, and it's rather passive-aggressive. Is this really the sort of situation you want to describe? I ask because the body of your question strikes me very differently from the question title.

Comment: Just because it's a fun idiom, "Blowing smoke" or "Blowing smoke up my <backside>" is a great idom for distracting and deceiving on purpose.

Comment: Related: [Idiom or set phrase for “pretending not to understand an innuendo”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241350/is-there-an-idiom-or-set-phrase-for-pretending-not-to-understand-an-innuendo)

Comment: Also: [“to pretend not to understand or know”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64614/idiom-phrase-which-means-to-pretend-not-to-understand-or-know)

Comment: In your example, speaker 2 is implicitly admitting the lie and *moving on*. If you intended to example diversion, for speaker 2 consider something like, "Well, if you're going to consider *that* a lie, what would you think if I asked you about the weather? You know, if I asked 'hot enough for you?' Just last weekend when we were on vacation on the lake I asked this guy 'hot enough for you?', and he said 'how about them Yankees?' I gotta tell you, I don't follow football, and we weren't in the deep South, so I don't know what he was talking about, but...." And so on.

Answer (score 24):

[**change the subject**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+the+subject)

This is indeed an idiom in its own right.

e.g.

I can't get any straight answers from you if you keep *changing the subject.*

Comment: This doesn't seem like an idiom; to me, "idiom" carries the connotation of not meaning what it literally says. In this case, the subject is assumed to refer to the subject of the conversation, and you're changing that subject. Unrelated to that, though, it's a common phrase that has the intended meaning

Comment: I agree, it's not an idiom.

Comment: Indeed, *changing the subject* most certainly *is* a common idiom, and only feels literal because it is so common in vernacular. Counter e.g. : A hairdresser has a subject for a client, and in the process of her work, she changes the subject by cutting their hair. This is an improper use of the idiom and proves that it is an idiom. There is no way to tell from the words *change the subject* that it concerns talking or discussion, thus, it is a group of words established by usage that has a meaning beyond the individual words. Helps to understand what an idiom is.

Comment: "Jack runs." is a sentence, with a subject and a predicate. To literally "change the subject," one would alter the sentence, e.g. "Jane runs." But to use the idiom *change the subject* properly, one might say "Jack sails," but this is literally the same subject with a different predicate, thus the meaning of *change the subject* is not deducible from the meaning of the individual words alone, and is only understood through its usage.

Answer (score 17):

I hear this given as the process of **deflecting**:

> **deflect** *v*
>   To turn aside or cause to turn aside; bend or deviate.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deflect)

Comment: Isn't deflecting more or less answering with a non-answer, rather than actually changing the subject? "Did you take the last cookie?" > "Do you think I'm a thief?" It deflects the original question, but doesn't change the subject really.

Comment: @Flater: It's a form of subject-changing, in my view.

Comment: I feel this is subjective, but I find there's a difference in giving a topical answer that avoids the goal of the question, and just talking about something completely unrelated (as in OP's example, start talking about the weather without any provocation to)

Comment: It might even be more accurate to say that subject-changing is a form of deflection, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 17):

*Pivoting* or *dodging the question* comes to mind based on how I would describe politicians.

Comment: This is probably the closest to capturing the meaning of OP's example.

Comment: I think dodging the question is great and if it were the only answer I'd upvote, but I wouldn't want people to think I was upvoting "pivoting" so I guess I can't?

Answer (score 15):

Are you looking for *steer the conversation away*:

Example: Helen tried to steer the conversation away from her recent problems.

[image]

*From Words and Their Meaning by Howard Jackson*

Comment: This feels like the most fitting idiom. But it could use some reference. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[Beat about the bush](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+around+the+bush) may convey the idea:

> - (Fig.) to avoid answering a question; to stall; to waste time.
>
>   - *Stop beating around the bush and answer my question. Let's stop beating about the bush and discuss this matter.*

The Free Dictionary

You can find related expressions here: [to change from one subject or discussion to another](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-change-from-one-subject-or-discussion-to-another) (www.macmillandictionary.com)

Note also the expression *[to dodge a question](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dodge):*

> - to evade (an obligation, for example) by cunning, trickery, or deceit: *kept dodging the reporter's questions.*

Answer (score 7):

If someone answered my question with irrelevant comments, I'd probably call it *evasion* or *evading the question*.

Comment: This - I was wracking my brain to think of the right phrase and had this on the tip of my tongue - Fits perfectly IMHO!

Comment: I'd also add that someone who does this is being "Evasive".

Answer (score 6):

To [**sidetrack**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidetracking)

> e.g. *"He sidetracked my questions about the project with small talk about the weather "*

which [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidetracking) defines as

> v.tr. -- 1. **To divert from a main issue or course:**

which derives from its literal meaning:

> 3. To switch from a main railroad track to a siding.

Comment: Please see our Help Center for [How to reference material written by others](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Note especially the part about how your post needs to be **mostly your own words**. Also please read [the meta post here, including “Plagiarised material may be deleted summarily without warning.…However, if a citation isn’t added after a reminder, or **an edit to add one is rolled back**, then the quote or the post containing it might be subject to deletion.”](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981) I added a reference for you ***which you rolled back.***

Comment: @tchrist. That's incorrect. My post had always very clearly included an URL citation to the Free Dictionary, on line one. That **is** a citation. It was unnecessary to duplicate it also by spelling out the name of the site. The "name of the original author" is clearly unknown; "the Free Dictionary" is not an author; it's a source. You might have simply said *"Here on English.SE we insist that a citation not just be an URL but also spell out the name of the source"*. Are we clear there never is/was any plagiarism? If you want to insist I spell out the name of the source, then just say so.

Comment: No, it is of course not plagiarism. The problem was that your reference must survive even if the link is not functional (some of the reuse scenarios allow this), so it is best to spell it out. Otherwise it becomes unattributed. It would still be best if answers had something of your own words, which this one does not.

Comment: @tchrist: perhaps for ephemeral links, but TheFreeDictionary.com should be with us for as long as SE itself... [What's the business model for free online dictionaries such as "The free dictionary" or "The Thesaurus"](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-business-model-for-free-online-dictionaries-such-as-The-free-dictionary-or-The-Thesaurus). As to wording, in this case the definition is self-explanatory, and I wrote a usage example of my own.

Comment: It isn't that the Free Dictionary is going away. It's that the content can be reused without links active.

Comment: @tchrist: That doesn't make any sense to me. If I post parts of their definition here, with an URL, then I both cited them and the reference survives even if the site dies.

Answer (score 3):

*Prevaricate* maybe?

> To speak or act in an evasive way

Comment: Wow, nice find. A single word whose *only* definition is that which was requested and whose idiomatic synonyms are half of these other answers. I get the feeling that if this was a comment asking, "so you want an idiom for *prevaricate?*", it'd have been upvoted through the roof.

Comment: Aww, what. Who downvoted this? If ever there was a word to replace an idiom, this would be it.

Comment: I won't touch it, but prevaricate is not the word you want.  In your example there was nothing evasive, it was blunt trauma.

Answer (score 3):

If he is just being evasive, you can say he *talked around the subject*:

> #### talk around something
>
> > to talk, but avoid talking directly about the subject.
> > *You are just talking around the matter! I want a straight answer!
> > He never really said anything. He just talked around the issue.*
>
> <sub>T[he Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+around)</sub>

However, if the purpose is to perpetuate the *lie* that you allude to in the example situation, then you can say he is giving you a *snow job*:

> #### snow job
>
> > An effort to deceive, persuade, or overwhelm with insincere talk. For example,
> >     *Peter tried to give the officer a snow job about an emergency at the hospital but he got a speeding ticket all the same.*
> >     This slangy expression, originating in the military during World War II, presumably alludes to the idiom *snow under*.
>
> <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snow+job)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

*Deflecting* is probably the best answer — but this is also sometimes called *misdirection*.

Answer (score 1):

## [*go off on a tangent*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off+on+a+tangent)

e.g.

> Sorry, I went *off on a tangent* and forgot your question . . . what were we talking about?

Comment: Going off on a tangent is usually not *intentional*, though.

Comment: @neminem Subjects are tangential purely by the relationships between their principles, not by the intent of their discussion. For example, I can go off on a tangent intentionally by announcing "Not to go on a tangent, but..."

Answer (score 1):

Also to throw out a *red herring*:

> Does this dress make me look fat?
>
> Oh, look, the kitchen's on fire!

or

> Does this dress make me look fat?
>
> Um, you've got something on your nose.
>
> (Finger swipe to nose.  Big hug and kiss)
>
> We need to  leave soon or we'll be late. You look terrific.   Is my tie straight?

Answer (score 1):

"To throw sand (or dust) in someone's eyes" might also serve:

> throw dust in someone's eyes:
>   Mislead someone, as in The governor's press aide threw dust in their eyes, talking about a flight at the airport when he was heading for the highway . This metaphoric expression alludes to throwing dust or sand in the air to confuse a pursuing enemy. [Mid-1700s]  (thefreedictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

> ...profuse talk about irrelevant things...

You're looking for [*bloviate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bloviate) or its synonyms. Per Oxford Dictionaries Online, *bloviate* means:

> Talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way.

Synonyms include *yammer, blather, babble, prattle*, and *chatter*.

Answer (score 0):

[*Filibuster* from Oxford Dictionaries Online, not the OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/filibuster):

> Noun
>
> an action such as a prolonged speech that obstructs progress in a legislative assembly while not technically contravening the required procedures

This word wold seem to fit your needs in that it speaks to "profuse talk" that is off topic and for the purposes of evading a topic.  While the formal definition refers to an action taken in a legislative assembly,there is enough common understanding of the meaning (in the US, at least) for the word to be applied in social contexts as well.

example:  I wanted to address the budget shortfall in the meeting but my boss used up all the time with a filibuster about his cats.

On a personal note, I have a coworker named Phillip who is frequently overly loquacious at inopportune moments.  When this happen I usually note that I have been "Philabustered"  (True story)

Answer (score -1):

"derail" the conversation -- carries the same meaning as "sidetrack" in that instead of shunting the conversation off onto another topic, you push it completely off the track.